# rpyc_classic.py in azure bash environment

Tags: python, bash, azure, rpyc

How to run **rpyc_classic.py** python file in azure bash environment?

I have tried to install wheel getting below exception.

> pip install [options]  ... no such option:
>   --use-wheel –

help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install rpyc using [pip](https://rpyc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#download-and-install) as follows:

```
pip install rpyc
```

or

```
pip install rpyc --user
```

Once installed, you can run `rpyc_classic.py` or `python bin/rpyc_classic.py` to start the server.

Another way is to clone the git repository for [rpyc](https://github.com/tomerfiliba/rpyc):

```
git clone https://github.com/tomerfiliba/rpyc.git
```

Then `cd` into the `rpyc/bin` folder and run the rpyc_classic.py file. You would then see something like this:

[image: run rpyc_classic.py]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok..let me try and ping you

Comment: pip install rpyc --user was installed successfully, but while running   python rpyc_classic.py  in azure bash environment nothing responded.. Expected result server started..help me to resolve, thanks.

Comment: Please try the git clone option mentioned above.

Comment: @Karthik.M Any luck with git clone?

Comment: Glad to know it helped! :)